# Is there a UIBezierPath equivalent of CGPath's `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)`?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Constructing custom variations of rounded rectangles is fussy business. The Swift V 5.1 answer in this thread:

[Swift: UIBezierPath Stroke Animation from Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839987/swift-uibezierpath-stroke-animation-from-center)

Describes out to draw a rounded rectangle starting from the top center, so you can animate stroking it starting from that point.

It uses the UIBezierPath method `addArc(withCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)` to draw the corner arcs of the rounded rectangle.

Getting the code right to draw the connected series of line segments and quarter arcs requires quite a bit of care, plus some knowledge of trig to figure out the angles of the different arcs for each quadrant.

CGPath has a variation on addArc, `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)`, that works differently. It takes "tangent end" points that define the arc in a way that's less fussy to set up (once you figure out how it works.)

I can't find an equivalent method for UIBezierPath. Am I missing something? I guess the answer is to create a `CGPath` (or rather, `CGMutablePath` using calls to `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)` and then use the UIBezierPath initializer that takes a CGPath, but that is an added step that makes the code a little bit more confusing.

Comment: i think if you are working with shape than use `CAShapeLayer` or working with text than use `CATextLayer` it might helps you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no `UIBezierPath` equivalent to the `CGPath` method `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)`.

I guess the answer is to just use `CGPath` when you want to add arcs in the form `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)`, and then convert the result to a `UIBezierPath` using the `UIBezierPath.init(cgPath:)` initializer.

At first I was thinking I could write an extension of `UIBezierPath` that would add a `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)` method to `UIBezierPath`, but that would get very messy, since `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)` uses the current pen position in the active path to figure out the first tangent line.

Comment: "uses the current pen position" do you mean the currentPoint https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624352-currentpoint ?

Comment: Yup. It looks like both `UIBezierPath` and `CGPath` expose a read-write `currentPoint` property, so it might be possible to read the current point from the bezier path and use it in an extension that builds an arc using CGPath `addArc(tangent1End:tangent2End:radius:transform:)`